# Given the eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix A, how can we "immediately see that the $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues since $AU=\Lambda U$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the notes I'm working through the following is said:

The eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix A, is $A=U\Lambda U^T$.

Later in the notes, it's said that "if A is multiplied with U we immediately see that $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues since $AU=\Lambda U$

I understand that by definition $\Lambda$ is the matrix of eigenvalues but how do we immediately see that $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues since $AU=\Lambda U$? At the moment I don't really see the significance of this statement.

Comment: You might want to look into the relationship between $Q$ and $U$

Comment: if $U$ is invertible, then what you've written is $A=\Lambda$